# I am having trouble excluding a custom taxonomy from an archive page for a custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have written a piece of code to build a  paginated archive page for a custom post type. I cannot exclude a certain custom taxonomy. can anyone help, please?

```
$temp = $wp_query;     
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=30&post_type=my_custom_post_type'.'&paged='.$paged);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the tax_query parameter in query array like here:

```
  $query_args = array(
  'showposts' => 30,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',       
  'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'custom-taxonomy-name',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => 'slug-name', 
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN')
                ),
           )
 );

$wp_query->query($query_args);
```

Please write your custom taxonomy name at the place of 'custom-taxonomy-name' and taxonomy slug name at the place of 'slug-name'